# Two questions about bijectivity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be a map, $f : X \to Y$

I understood that if you find a right-inverse = $g$ (left-inverse = $g'$) the function is surjective (injective). Bijectivity requires both but must $g = g'$? Can we apply the Lemma from group theory that an inverse is unambiguous? But the Problem is that if a function $f$ is for ex. surjective we can find multiple right-inverses, we can define $g$ that every element of $Y$ is mapped on one preimage, for $g'$ we pick another preimage for at least one element and then $g$ is not $g'$.

My second question is about the amount of elements of $X$ and $Y$.

$f$ has an inverse $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is bijective $\Rightarrow$ $|X| = |Y|$.

Can somebody explain the direct Connection between the first statement and the last statement of the conclusion above?

Comment: You are asking why $f$ is bijective implies that $|X|=|Y|$?  That is the *definition* of cardinality.

Comment: No if we find an inverse to a random function with f : X ->Y why are the sets equal?

Comment: The sets aren't necessarily equal.  The *cardinalities* of the sets are equal.  And the cardinalities are equal iff there is a bijection between them *because that is how cardinality is defined*.  [See wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality).  As for why $f$ being an invertible function (*i.e. has a right functional inverse and a left functional inverse*) implies that it is bijective, that is a standard exercise in any elementary set theory course.

Comment: As for the question of if $f$ has a right functional inverse and $f$ has a left functional inverse, the result is that the right inverse *must* be the same as the left inverse, again this is a standard homework exercise for a course on elementary set theory.

Comment: And if you find a rightinverse and a leftinverse but the two are not the same does it imply the existence of an inverse? And why there are several inverses? I thought that an inverse must be unique, does that mean that (F,o) is not a group with f being the set of all maps from X -> Y, and X,Y being sets with equal cardinality, and o being the Operator to link two functions.

Comment: If you find a right inverse and a left inverse then they must both be the same and it must be unique.  If you find multiple different right inverses that implies that no left inverse can possibly exist.  Similarly if there are multiple different left inverses then no right inverse can possibly exist.

Comment: As for the question of the group., no, your set is not a group.  It is not even closed under your group operation.  If you were to change it to be the set of all bijective maps from $X$ *to itself* where the group operation is composition, yes this *will* be a group.

Answer (score 1):

> If you have a right inverse and left inverse simultaneously then they must be equal.

- Suppose that $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$
- Suppose that $g$ is a function from $Y$ to $X$ which satisfies $f(g(y))=y$ for all $y\in Y$ (*that is $g$ is a right functional inverse of $f$*)
- Suppose that $h$ is a function from $Y$ to $X$ which satisfies $h(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in X$ (*that is $h$ is a left functional inverse of $f$*).

Notice then that $h(f(g(y))) = h(y)$ by applying the property that $f(g(y))=y$.

Notice also that $h(f(g(y))) = g(y)$ by applying the property that $h(f(x))=x$ and using $g(y)$ in place of $x$.

That is to say, if $f$ has both a right inverse and a left inverse, then those inverses must be equal to one another. $\square$

---

> If you have multiple different right inverses then no left inverse can exist.

- Suppose that $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$
- Suppose that $g_1$ is a function from $Y$ to $X$ which satisfies $f(g_1(y))=y$ for all $y\in Y$ (*that is $g_1$ is a right functional inverse of $f$*)
- Suppose that $g_2$ is a function from $Y$ to $X$ which satisfies $f(g_2(y))=y$ for all $y\in Y$ (*that is $g_2$ is a right functional inverse of $f$*)
- Suppose that $g_1\neq g_2$.  That is to say, there is at least one $y\in Y$ such that $g_1(y)\neq g_2(y)$

Now... suppose for contradictory purposes that there exists a left-inverse $h$.  We would have then:

$h(f(g_1(y))) = h(y)$ as well as $h(f(g_2(y)))= h(y)$ by applying the property that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are right inverses of $f$ and so $h(f(g_1(y)))= h(f(g_2(y)))$.

On the other hand, by instead applying the property that $h$ is a left-inverse of $f$ we get:

$h(f(g_1(y)))=g_1(y)$ and $h(f(g_2(y)))=g_2(y)$.

But, as $h(f(g_1(y)))$ was equal to $h(f(g_2(y)))$, it follows from transitivity that $g_1(y)=g_2(y)$, contradicting that $g_1$ was supposed to be different than $g_2$, thereby proving that $h$ must therefore not exist. $\square$

---

I leave the proof that $f$ has an inverse if and only if $f$ is bijective to you.

As for the question of cardinality, the very *definition* of the meaning of the symbols $|X|=|Y|$ is that there exists a bijection between $X$ and $Y$.  No proof is required because it is from the very definition.